# How can I listen for an action performed on the store triggered by one component on another component using vue and vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Component 1:

```
<template>
  <button @click="restartForm">Perform Action</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
  ...mapActions('form', [
            'restartForm',
        ]),
  }
}
</script>
```

I want, in component 2, to "listen" that this action has been performed in the store and perform another action based on this.

Component 2:

```
...
  computed: {
    ...mapActions('form',['restartForm'])
  },
  watch: {
    restartForm() {
      // do stuff
    }
  },
```

Does not work though. I could watch the state changing but I feel like it shouldn't be done like this.

Comment: Do not watch `restartForm` (action that will update the state) but the state itself, so `watch + mapState 'form'` or whatever is the name of your state. You don't need to know who/how/when changed the state, just check the current state and react accordingly.